# Differentiability of a C^2 function

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is as follows:

Let $U$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and consider $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function of class $C^2$. Show that for every $x \in U$, $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^m$,
$$
f''(x)(v, w) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{m} \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j }(x) v_i w_j,
$$
where $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_m), v = (v_1, \ldots, v_m)$ and $w = (w_1, \ldots, w_m)$.

**I've made an attempt, I'd appreciate any feedback if it is wrong or if any mistake was made:**

If $f$ is $C^2$ then it is twice differentiable on $x \in U$.
We have that
$$
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} (a) \cdot v_i
$$
Now,
$$
f''(x) (v, w) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial w} \left( \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v} \right) (x) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial w} \left( \sum_{i=1}^m v_i \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \right) (x) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{m} v_i w_j \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} (x).
$$

I feel like this is it, but I might be missing something. What do you think?

Comment: Isn't $f''(x)$ just an $m\times m$ symmetric Hessian matrix (because $f$ is $C^2$)? What exactly is meant by the notation $f''(x)(v,w)$ here?

Comment: This notation also may be seen as $f''(x) \cdot v \cdot w$, if it helps.

Comment: Okay. I am still unsure what the notation means. Your use of $\cdot$ seems to imply a dot product, but the dot product of $v\cdot w$ is a scalar. Also $f''(x)$ is a matrix isn't it? So what does $f''(x)\cdot ...$ mean?

Comment: I see your point, I thought the same when I first saw this question (it was on an exam I just took). I'm not sure if the function should map to the real numbers.
This is my take in the question as it is

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't mean $v^T f''(x) w$ (where $v$ and $w$ are column vectors)? Then this is just a matrix multiplication problem. Just apply the definition of matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

The $ij$th entry of the matrix $f''(x)$ is $$\frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}.$$ Thus the product of the $m\times m$ matrix $f''(x)$ with the $m\times 1$ matrix $w$ is the $m\times 1$ matrix $u$ with $i$th entry $$u_{i}=(f''(x) w)_i=\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}w_j.$$ Finally, multiply the $1\times m$ matrix $v^T$ by the $m\times 1$ matrix $u$ to get $$v^Tf''(x)w=v^Tu=\sum_{i=1}^mv_iu_i=\sum_{i=1}^mv_i\sum_{j=1} \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}w_j=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^m  \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}v_iw_j$$ as required.

Comment: Thanks, I believe you are correct in using $v^T$ on multiplying on the left side of $f''$, it makes more sense.